# Content Deployment and AllowUnsafeUpdates

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have this bit of code...

```
using (SPSite sitecollection = new SPSite(siteUrl))
{
    using (SPWeb web = sitecollection.OpenWeb(webUrl))
    {
        try
        {                        
            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

            ContentDeploymentJob.AddQuickDeployObject(web,
                        Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPDeploymentObjectType.ListItem,
                        itemUrl);                        
            web.Update();
        }
        finally
        {
            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
        }
    }
}
```

which should add an item to the content deployment for the specified web.
However I get this error...

> Updates are currently disallowed on GET requests.  To allow updates on a GET, set the 'AllowUnsafeUpdates' property on SPWeb.

yet i've set AllUnsafeUpdates to true. Is it me, am I missing something?

Comment: Interesting as you are using the same code shown by MS in http://blogs.msdn.com/uksharepoint/archive/2009/02/13/quick-tip-adding-documents-from-document-libraries-to-a-quick-deploy-job.aspx so it should work... What context is this code running from - web part, application page, something else?

Comment: that's the one, exactly the same code. I've created an application page so i'm assuming the code is running in that context although I haven't set anything specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try running web.update() before running the contentDeploymentJob?  It looks to me that you are setting the property but not saving it.

Comment: i moved the web.update to the line above the contentdeployment job but still receive the same error.